# How do I block web crawler in Azure Cloud Web App?

Tags: azure, web-crawler

Does Azure Cloud .NET web app allow for robots.txt or X-Robots-Tag HTTP header and .htaccess configuration? Does Azure Portal have a setting to stop crawling on a web app? Can crawling be blocked via web.config file? I am not sure what the best way to do it is. We have a DEV, TEST, and PROD servers. I want to block on DEV and TEST and allow on PROD. I know robots.txt is easiest, but not best, but that is assuming it works in Azure Cloud.

Comment: Which services are wanting to stop crawling your site; Google, Bing and other search engines? There are many ways to do this; like restricting access, enabling authentication, robots.txt, meta tags. If you could provide a little more context you will probably get a better answer.